# Identifying whether or not that the map from $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphism.

Tags: ring-homomorphism

Let $f$ be a map from quotient ring from $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ to
$\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$f(z+8\mathbb{Z}) = z+4\mathbb{Z}$.
Check that whether or not that $f$ is isomorphism.

My attempt: **(Edited)**

For homomorphism,
let $x+8\mathbb{Z},y+8\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
f((x+8\mathbb{Z})+(y+8\mathbb{Z})) &= f((x+y)+8\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= (x+y)+4\mathbb{Z} \\
&= (x+4\mathbb{Z})+(y+8\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= f(x+8\mathbb{Z}) + f(y+8\mathbb{Z})
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
f((x+8\mathbb{Z})(y+8\mathbb{Z})) &=
f(xy + 8\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= xy+4\mathbb{Z} \\
&= (x+4\mathbb{Z})(y+4\mathbb{Z}) \\
&= f(x+8\mathbb{Z})f(y+8\mathbb{Z})
\end{align*}

Thus, $f$ is a homomorphism.

Next, $f$ is injective iff $Ker(f) = \{\bar{0}\}$.

If $x+8\mathbb{Z} \in Ker(f)$, then
$0+4\mathbb{Z} = f(x+8\mathbb{Z}) = x+4\mathbb{Z}$. This implies that $4|a$.
If $4|a$, then
$f(x+8\mathbb{Z})=x+4\mathbb{Z} = 0+4\mathbb{Z}$ and $x+8\mathbb{Z} \in Ker(f)$.

It follows that
$Ker(f) = \{8\mathbb{Z},4+8\mathbb{Z}\} \neq \{\bar{0}\}$.

And then, $f$ is not isomorphism.

Am I true? Where is the mistakes of mine above? Any idea? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You are almost right. But you have not proved $f$ is a ring homomorphism - what about the multiplication?

Comment: Oh, I've forgot for it. Let me edit.

Comment: ancientmathematician is right, and also $f$ is indeed a ring homomorphism. Either way, $f$ is not a bijection. In this case, it's probably faster to show that $f$ is not injective by direct calculation -- $f(1+8\mathbb{Z})=1+4\mathbb{Z}=f(5+8\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got it now.

Comment: Not that it's probably necessary for this problem, but it's an important skill to understand why this map is even well-defined. A similar-looking formula, for example, proposing a function from $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ to 
$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$f(z+8\mathbb{Z}) = z+6\mathbb{Z}$ would actually not be well-defined; do you see what the difference is?

Comment: Since $6$ doesn't divide $8$ right?